# How does Microsoft decide making methods static/member in C#?

Tags: c#, static

I've noticed that there are many static methods in FCL that affect only single object, for example `Array.Resize`. What's the point making them static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance methods can only modify the member properties of an object. In your example of `Array.Resize`, the method modifies the array reference itself, which is why it is static and takes the parameter by reference.

When you do this:

```
int[] arr = ...;
Array.Resize(ref arr, 10);
```

the `arr` reference itself is modified, which would not be possible by calling a method on `arr`.

Alternatively, in a language such as Java which does not support passing by reference, it would be declared to return the new array.